# RXJS + Redux Observable - how to merge a new stream?

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

We've recently picked up Redux Observable and it's been a great way to manage high level action orchestration.

One problem I've recently is responding to the result of a data fetch. We have a generic service function which returns a RXJS observable. Normally we select what ever data we need and subscribe.

I thought this would be fairly natural with redux-observable. Use MapTo on the Epic, and return the RXJS observer with the subsequent select.

From what I can tell Redux-observable doesn't subscribe so nothing happens.

Does anyone have an example of how it should work?

`export function redirectUserToEndpointEpic(action$) {
   return action$.ofType(LOCATION_CHANGE)
      .filter(action=>action.payload.pathname !== '/'))
      .mapTo(action=>authService.getObserver() // returns a stream which has not been subscribed to
         .select(userData=>userData.defaultPath)
         .map(push);
}`

Comment: Can you perhaps provide some example code, even if not functional, to better illustrate the question?

Comment: Sure. I'll psudo code is `export function redirectUserToEndpointEpic(action$) {
   return action$.ofType(LOCATION_CHANGE)
      .filter(action=>action.payload.pathname !== '/'))
      .mapTo(action=>authService.getObserver() // returns a stream which has not been subscribed to
         .select(userData=>userData.defaultPath)
         .map(push);
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is actually correct. The dependency was using 'rx' library rather than 'rxjs' which caused a conflict.

Thanks all